# Exchange 2013 -> 2016 Move Requests Stuck

Tags: windows, exchange, email-server, exchange-2013, mailbox

I'm trying to migrate users from Exchange 2013 to Exchange 2016 but when I create a move request, *even with only 1 mailbox in the queue, with a size of a few kilobytes*, it'll inevitably end up at **RelinquishedWlmStall**.

There are no performance issues on either server, and I initially ran the move overnight. Any pointers to solutions or where I could gather more information about the issue?

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Changed **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSExchange ResourceHealth**.
- Used the **Highest** and **Emergency** priorities.
- Adjusted **MSExchangeMailboxReplication.exe.config**.
- Executed **Get-ExchangeServer | ForEach {New-SettingOverride -Component "WorkloadManagement" -Name "$_ MRS Override" -Server $*.Name -Section MailboxReplicationService -Reason "$* Temporary Move" -Parameters Classification=Urgent -MinVersion 15.0}**
- Restarted both servers multiple times.

Here are the move statistics:

```
ArchiveGuid                            :
Status                                 : InProgress
StatusDetail                           : RelinquishedWlmStall
SyncStage                              : None
Flags                                  : IntraOrg, Pull
RequestStyle                           : IntraOrg
Direction                              : Pull
IsOffline                              : False
Protect                                : False
DoNotPreserveMailboxSignature          : False
Priority                               : Normal
WorkloadType                           : Local
Suspend                                : False
SuspendWhenReadyToComplete             : False
IgnoreRuleLimitErrors                  : False
RecipientTypeDetails                   : UserMailbox
SourceVersion                          : Version 15.0 (Build 1320.0)
TargetVersion                          : Version 15.1 (Build 225.0)
SourceArchiveDatabase                  :
SourceArchiveVersion                   :
SourceArchiveServer                    :
TargetArchiveDatabase                  :
TargetArchiveVersion                   :
TargetArchiveServer                    :
RemoteHostName                         :
RemoteGlobalCatalog                    :
StartAfter                             :
CompleteAfter                          :
RemoteCredentialUsername               :
RemoteDatabaseName                     :
RemoteDatabaseGuid                     :
RemoteArchiveDatabaseName              :
RemoteArchiveDatabaseGuid              :
TargetDeliveryDomain                   :
ArchiveDomain                          :
BadItemLimit                           : 10
BadItemsEncountered                    : 0
LargeItemLimit                         : 0
LargeItemsEncountered                  : 0
AllowLargeItems                        : True
StartTimestamp                         :
InitialSeedingCompletedTimestamp       :
FinalSyncTimestamp                     :
CompletionTimestamp                    :
SuspendedTimestamp                     :
OverallDuration                        : 05:07:15.8805147
TotalFinalizationDuration              : 00:00:00
TotalDataReplicationWaitDuration       : 00:00:00
TotalSuspendedDuration                 : 00:00:00
TotalFailedDuration                    : 00:00:00
TotalQueuedDuration                    : 00:02:07.1040967
TotalInProgressDuration                : 01:50:11.4364136
TotalStalledDueToCIDuration            : 00:45:05.4836894
TotalStalledDueToHADuration            : 00:00:00
TotalStalledDueToMailboxLockedDuration : 00:00:00
TotalStalledDueToReadThrottle          : 00:00:00
TotalStalledDueToWriteThrottle         : 00:00:00
TotalStalledDueToReadCpu               : 00:00:00
TotalStalledDueToWriteCpu              : 00:00:00
TotalStalledDueToReadUnknown           : 00:00:00
TotalStalledDueToWriteUnknown          : 00:00:00
TotalTransientFailureDuration          : 00:00:00
TotalProxyBackoffDuration              : 00:00:00
TotalIdleDuration                      : 00:40:18.5876769
MRSServerName                          :
TotalMailboxSize                       : 64.08 MB (67,188,711 bytes)
TotalMailboxItemCount                  : 295
TotalArchiveSize                       :
TotalArchiveItemCount                  :
BytesTransferred                       : 0 B (0 bytes)
BytesTransferredPerMinute              : 0 B (0 bytes)
ItemsTransferred                       : 0
PercentComplete                        : 0
CompletedRequestAgeLimit               : 7.00:00:00
PositionInQueue                        :
InternalFlags                          : None
FailureCode                            :
FailureType                            :
FailureSide                            :
Message                                : Informational: The request has been temporarily postponed due to unfavorable
                                         server health or budget limitations. MRS will attempt to continue processing
                                         the request again after ****.
FailureTimestamp                       :
IsValid                                : True
ValidationMessage                      :
DiagnosticInfo                         :
Report                                 :
ObjectState                            : New
```

Here's a cleaned-up report:

```
[EXCHANGE2013] '' created move request.
[EXCHANGE2016] The Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Replication service 'exchange2016.hostname' (15.1.225.37 caps:7FFF) is examining the request.
[EXCHANGE2016] Connected to target mailbox 'uuid1 (Primary)', database 'Target Database', Mailbox server 'exchange2016.hostname' Version 15.1 (Build 225.0).
[EXCHANGE2016] Connected to source mailbox 'uuid1 (Primary)', database 'Source Database', Mailbox server 'exchange2013.hostname' Version 15.0 (Build 1320.0), proxy server 'exchange2013.hostname' 15.0.1320.0 caps:0400001F7FFFFFCB07FFFF.
[EXCHANGE2016] Relinquishing job because of large delays due to unfavorable server health or budget limitations.
[EXCHANGE2016] The Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Replication service 'exchange2016.hostname' (15.1.225.37 caps:7FFF) is examining the request.
[EXCHANGE2016] Connected to target mailbox 'uuid1 (Primary)', database 'Target Database', Mailbox server 'exchange2016.hostname' Version 15.1 (Build 225.0).
[EXCHANGE2016] Connected to source mailbox 'uuid1 (Primary)', database 'Source Database', Mailbox server 'exchange2013.hostname' Version 15.0 (Build 1320.0), proxy server 'exchange2013.hostname' 15.0.1320.0 caps:0400001F7FFFFFCB07FFFF.
[EXCHANGE2016] Relinquishing job because of large delays due to unfavorable server health or budget limitations.
[EXCHANGE2016] The Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Replication service 'exchange2016.hostname' (15.1.225.37 caps:7FFF) is examining the request.
[EXCHANGE2016] Connected to target mailbox 'uuid1 (Primary)', database 'Target Database', Mailbox server 'exchange2016.hostname' Version 15.1 (Build 225.0).
[EXCHANGE2016] Connected to source mailbox 'uuid1 (Primary)', database 'Source Database', Mailbox server 'exchange2013.hostname' Version 15.0 (Build 1320.0), proxy server 'exchange2013.hostname' 15.0.1320.0 caps:0400001F7FFFFFCB07FFFF.
[EXCHANGE2016] Relinquishing job because of large delays due to unfavorable server health or budget limitations.
[EXCHANGE2016] The Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Replication service 'exchange2016.hostname' (15.1.225.37 caps:7FFF) is examining the request.
[EXCHANGE2016] Connected to target mailbox 'uuid1 (Primary)', database 'Target Database', Mailbox server 'exchange2016.hostname' Version 15.1 (Build 225.0).
[EXCHANGE2016] Connected to source mailbox 'uuid1 (Primary)', database 'Source Database', Mailbox server 'exchange2013.hostname' Version 15.0 (Build 1320.0), proxy server 'exchange2013.hostname' 15.0.1320.0 caps:0400001F7FFFFFCB07FFFF.
[EXCHANGE2016] The Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Replication service 'exchange2016.hostname' (15.1.225.37 caps:7FFF) is examining the request.
[EXCHANGE2016] Connected to target mailbox 'uuid1 (Primary)', database 'Target Database', Mailbox server 'exchange2016.hostname' Version 15.1 (Build 225.0).
[EXCHANGE2016] Connected to source mailbox 'uuid1 (Primary)', database 'Source Database', Mailbox server 'exchange2013.hostname' Version 15.0 (Build 1320.0), proxy server 'exchange2013.hostname' 15.0.1320.0 caps:0400001F7FFFFFCB07FFFF.
[EXCHANGE2016] Relinquishing job because of large delays due to unfavorable server health or budget limitations.
```

And another related error I could find:

```
MigrationTransientException: Failed to communicate with the mailbox database. --> Failed to communicate with the mailbox database. --> MapiExceptionMdbOffline: Unable to make connection to the server. ‎(hr=0x80004005, ec=1142)‎ Diagnostic context: Lid: 41192 dwParam: 0x1 Lid: 63464 Lid: 34792 StoreEc: 0x6AB Lid: 51176 StoreEc: 0x80040115 Lid: 48104 Lid: 39912 StoreEc: 0x80040115 Lid: 41192 dwParam: 0x2 Lid: 49384 Lid: 51176 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 48104 Lid: 39912 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 41192 dwParam: 0x0 Lid: 49064 dwParam: 0x1 Lid: 37288 StoreEc: 0x6AB Lid: 49064 dwParam: 0x2 Lid: 38439 EMSMDBPOOL.EcPoolConnect called [length=48] Lid: 54823 EMSMDBPOOL.EcPoolConnect returned [ec=0x476][length=20][latency=31] Lid: 53361 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 51859 Lid: 33649 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 43315 Lid: 58225 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 39912 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 54129 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 50519 Lid: 59735 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 59199 Lid: 27356 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 65279 Lid: 52465 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 60065 Lid: 33777 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 59805 Lid: 52487 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 19778 Lid: 27970 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 17730 Lid: 25922 StoreEc: 0x476
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means what it says - there is a problem with the servers communicating. I have seen AV do this before - particularly AVAST, but also some others. If you have file level AV on the servers check it has the correct exclusions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There's no AV on either server and there's full bidirectional communication between them (they share the same switching fabric). Do you know anything else that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might face this problem in the future, the solution was to enable MAPI over HTTP: `Set-OrganizationConfig -MapiHttpEnabled $true`.